# How to return data from firestore in json?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a function (on server side) able to return data from firestore
but it always return me undefined

I tried to display it before returning it and I can see the value in my terminal.

```
exports.get_client = (ref)=> {
    ref.collection("clients/").get().then(function(coll) {
        let a= []
            coll.forEach(element => {
              a.push({"User": element.id, "data": element.data()})
              return a
            })
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

I expected [ { User: 'test@test.com',
    data:
     { email: 'test@test.com',
       family_name: 'test2',
       first_name: 'test' } } ]
but I had undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return a` line is just returning from the lambda function that you passed to `forEach`.  It's not actually returning anything from the function `get_client`.  If you have a value to return from `get_client`, you will have to do that outside of the lambda

```
exports.get_client = (ref)=> {
    return ref.collection("clients/").get().then(function(coll) {
        let a= []
        coll.forEach(element => {
            a.push({"User": element.id, "data": element.data()})
        })
        return a
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I try this but I have the same result, undefined.

Comment: I edited the code.  It was missing a return of the promise returned by `catch`.  The client will need to use this promise to get the final value when it becomes available.